# How to store in sql server response of bot

Tags: c#, sql-server, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm creating a bot using botframework , c# . I'm using also qnamaker. My questions is how to store in database the questions and answer of users. For the moment i can store in log table only message send by users as below :

MessagesController.cs :

```
   //   if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
           *************************
            // Log to Database
            // *************************

            // Instantiate the BotData dbContext
            Model.qnamakerbotdataEntities DB = new Model.qnamakerbotdataEntities();
            // Create a new UserLog object
            Model.UserLog NewUserLog = new Model.UserLog();

            // Set the properties on the UserLog object
            NewUserLog.Channel = activity.ChannelId;
            NewUserLog.UserID = activity.From.Id;
            NewUserLog.UserName = activity.From.Name;
            NewUserLog.created = DateTime.UtcNow;
            NewUserLog.Message = activity.Text.Truncate(500);

            // Add the UserLog object to UserLogs
            DB.UserLogs.Add(NewUserLog);
            // Save the changes to the database
            DB.SaveChanges();
```

Do you have an idea how to store message send by users and response of the bot ?

```
   using System;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
  using QnABot.API;
   using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals;

namespace QnABot.Dialogs
{
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, 
       IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        //var activity = await result as Activity;

        //// Prompt text
        //await context.PostAsync("Feel free to ask me");

        var privateData = context.PrivateConversationData;
        var privateConversationInfo = IncrementInfoCount(privateData, 
           BotStoreType.BotPrivateConversationData.ToString());
        var conversationData = context.ConversationData;
        var conversationInfo = IncrementInfoCount(conversationData, 
           BotStoreType.BotConversationData.ToString());
        var userData = context.UserData;
        var userInfo = IncrementInfoCount(userData, 
           BotStoreType.BotUserData.ToString());
        context.Wait(QnADialog);
                     PrivateData.SetValue(BotStoreType.BotPrivateConversationData.ToString(), 
       privateConversationInfo);
        conversationData.SetValue(BotStoreType.BotConversationData.ToString(), conversationInfo);
        userData.SetValue(BotStoreType.BotUserData.ToString(), userInfo);
    }

    private async Task QnADialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activityResult = await result as Activity;
        var query = activityResult.Text;

        var qnaResult = QnaApi.GetFirstQnaAnswer(query);

        if (qnaResult == null)
        {
            string message = $"Sorry, I did not understand . Please 
        reformulate your question";
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync(qnaResult.answers[0].answer);
        }


        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
    public class BotDataInfo
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    private BotDataInfo IncrementInfoCount(IBotDataBag botdata, string key)
    {
        BotDataInfo info = null;
        if (botdata.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            info = botdata.GetValue<BotDataInfo>(key);
            info.Count++;
        }
        else
            info = new BotDataInfo() { Count = 1 };

        return info;
       }
        }
           }
```

Comment: Well you have code on how to add a line to the log - where you have code to respond.. take the response and add it

Comment: @BugFinder i don't know the code how to catch the response ( this is my problem )

Comment: youve shown no code here about responding so we cant help you with that - read the code find the bit where its responding work from there.

Comment: @BugFinder i haven't show because i don't know the code ...or the mode let say how to do this ...this is the reason why i'm asking help :(

Comment: @user38 can you please post the code from your `RootDialog` and any other dialogs you have

Comment: @JasonSowers i'm trying to use a sample of azure document . Please see code updated

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like below.  Please note I did not have all your code to make this compile, but you should be able to adjust it if needed.  the main part is creating a reply like this `var reply = activityResult.CreateReply();` and then setting the text in the `message` variable in your `if-else`  then setting the text of the reply then sending it
`NewUserLog.Message = reply.Text;
await context.PostAsync(reply);`

```
    private async Task QnADialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activityResult = await result as Activity;
        var query = activityResult.Text;
        var reply = activityResult.CreateReply();

        var qnaResult = QnaApi.GetFirstQnaAnswer(query);
        string message = "";
        if (qnaResult == null)
        {
            message = $"Sorry, I did not understand. Please reformulate your question";

        }
        else
        {
            message = qnaResult.answers[0].answer;                
        }

        reply.Text = message;
        Model.qnamakerbotdataEntities DB = new Model.qnamakerbotdataEntities();
        // Create a new UserLog object
        Model.UserLog NewUserLog = new Model.UserLog();

        // Set the properties on the UserLog object
        NewUserLog.Channel = reply.ChannelId;
        NewUserLog.UserID = reply.From.Id;
        NewUserLog.UserName = reply.From.Name;
        NewUserLog.created = DateTime.UtcNow;

        NewUserLog.Message = reply.Text;
        await context.PostAsync(reply);

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
```

Comment: thank you ! I put this code in RootDialog.cs but need to add in MessageController.cs ...cause when i add :   Model.qnamakerentitiesEntities DB = new Model.qnamakerentitiesEntities();
            // Create a new UserLog object
            Model.UserLog NewUserLog = new Model.UserLog();
            NewUserLog.Response = reply.Text;
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);   this code in RootDialog.cs in my db this value is null ( not the real message that bot response )

Comment: you're welcome, please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: i appreciate so much your help but when i have to store Response of the bot also . I added this code :  NewUserLog.Response = qnaResult.answers[0].answer;  but this code is neccesary to be added at MessageController.cs also not only in RootDialog.cs I don't know how to add this in MessageController.cs

Comment: Your bot is not responding in the messages controller, so why do you need it there?  If it is responding in `MessagesController.cs`  please post the code in which it is responding so I can help you further.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to log the response in the messages controller?  If the bot is responding in the Dialog, why don't you want to log the response there?

Comment: Please Jason help how to store the answer comes from the bot , which is the code .